# Is using $Api.Session_ID in visualforce page to be used in force.com site vulnerable?

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, force.com-sites, guest-user

I am using $API.Session_Id in script in a VF page. I will be using this page for guest users. This {!$Api.session_id} returns some value. Is it a wrong way to get session id as this page will be used for site Guest users? Is it vulnerable?

`<apex:page controller="ABCcntr"><script> var token={!$Api.Session_ID}</script> </apex:page>`